# How to substract the percentage of divs with margins so they perfectly fit their parent?

Tags: html, css, stylus

With this HTML/CSS:

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS/STYLUS:

```
.row {
  max-width: 1230px
  margin: 0 auto
  width: 100%
}

.col-6 {
  margin: 5px
  float: left
  width: 50% - 10px
}
```

I expected the `.col-6` divs to fit perfectly their parent `.row`. But I was wrong:
[image]

What's the correct way to make the `.col-6` divs fit perfectly `.row` (horizontally)?

Comment: Is this pure CSS or are you using something like Bootstrap as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using calc();

```
width: calc(50% - 10px);
```